# dnsmasq - Disable integration of DHCP-configured hosts into the DNS

Tags: networking, dns, dhcp, hostname, dnsmasq

In a common dnsmasq installation, serving as both a DHCP server and a DNS server, the DHCP server integrates with the DNS server and registers the hostnames of DHCP-configured hosts into the DNS. For example, if a machine with hostname connects to the network, dnsmasq allows all other computers to resolve the newly connected machine's hostname to its assigned IP via DNS.

So, how can I disable this feature? I still want to dnsmasq to include the contents of */etc/hosts* (as well as any *adress=/example.com/1.2.3.4* stanzas in *dnsmasq.conf*) to the DNS. This seems trivial, but I've search online for a while now and haven't found anything useful. The only solution that comes to my mind is to two run two instances of dnsmasq, one exclusively as a DHCP server and the other as a DNS server.